# Connector for I2C sensor

Tags: i2c, wireless

Im about to develop some home automation. It should be possible to connect new sensors to the main computer. Thats a Arduino.

What can be used as a connector for the I2C sensors? It should be customer friendly. So something like RJ11 or USB. What can be used for that?

Is it possible to send data wirelessly from a I2C sensor?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

> What can be used as a connector for the I2C sensors? It should be customer friendly. So something like RJ11 or USB. What can be used for that?

Almost anything you like. Whatever is easy to get hold of and use. You only need 4 wires, and they are all low voltage, so nothing too fancy is needed.

> Is it possible to send data wirelessly from a I2C sensor?

No. But you can connect the I2C sensor to an Arduino then use that with a wireless interface of some form to send the data wirelessly.

One thing for you to know though:

**I2C is not suitable for long distance communications. A few inches to a foot or so is about the limit. Anything longer and you will start running into communication problems. For longer distance communications you need to use a more reliable protocol.**

Comment: Thanks a lot Majenko.
So i could use USB or RJ11? And would that work only work with a very short cable? So no 4m cable?
If i go for wireless, would i then be able to use like a Arduino Nano?

Comment: You could use those connectors if you choose, yes. But no 4m is not really on for I2C. Yes, you could use an Arduino Nano.

Comment: If i should find sensors that could be used with 4m of cable, what kind of sensors type is that?

Comment: Probably expensive and specialised. Most sensors are designed to be interfaced with something close by - often within the same circuit board or one closely connected. Normally you would take a sensor, add a small microcontroller, and some kind of transceiver (radio, RS-485, whatever) to transfer the data over a long distance. It's not the role of the sensor to do that sort of thing.

Comment: So i guess the easiest way is to make it wirelessly :-)
Thanks a lot for the help